# Emberjs maximum call stack when displaying hasMany

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and i have problem with display hasMany relation.

My Models:

```
App.Shop = DS.Model.extend({
                name:           DS.attr('string'),
                openSettings:   DS.hasMany('App.OpenSetting')
});
App.OpenSetting = DS.Model.extend({
                title:          DS.attr('string'),
                data:           DS.attr('string'),
                shopId:         DS.belongsTo('App.Shop')
});
```

I have mapping:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.Shop', { 
    openSettings:   { key: 'openSettings' }
});
DS.RESTAdapter.map('App.OpenSetting', { 
    shopId:         { key: 'shopId' }
});
```

In index.html in script i have:

```
{{#each model}}
   {{id}} - {{name}} # 
   {{#each openSettings}}
       {{title}}                 
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

But when object Shop has some relations in openSettings  (openSettings:[1,2]) then i get error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What i'm doing wrong?

Fixtures:

```
    App.Shop.FIXTURES = [
        {
            name: "Supermarket",
            id: 2,
            openSettings: [
                2, 5
            ]
        }
    ];

    App.OpenSetting.FIXTURES = [
        {
            title: "monday - friday",
            data: "8:00 - 24:00",
            id: 2,
            shopId: 2
        },
        {
            title: "saturday",
            data: "8:00 - 1:00",
            id: 5,
            shopId: 2
        }
    ];
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I got solution. Ember dont like field named "data"...

Comment: You could post that as an answer to your own question and mark as correct for those that have the same problem and stumble across this question in the future. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ember throws that error when field is named "data". After change, all works fine.

Comment: anyone knows why is that? i've renamed by field to `items` and it works now, but I'd like to know why `data` does not work? is there some official doc with reserved field names?